# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckBox

Tags: android

A few days ago my code was working fine. I'm building and testing on a leimin z4 Android version 4.4.2 sdk 19. All was well. I was also testing on tecno n8s.

Everything was ok until yesterday when I run things my `WebView` and long click on a `CardView` are all giving me this errors:

```
Process: kamble.travelite.com, PID: 27771
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.createCustomViewInternal(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:211)
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.access$000(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:20)
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:302)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3108)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3172)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1718)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3019)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.createCustomViewInternal(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:211) 
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.access$000(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:20) 
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:302) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3108) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3172) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1718) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3019) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class <unknown>
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:164)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:148)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.initTitle(ActionBarView.java:845)
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.setDisplayOptions(ActionBarView.java:663)
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:227)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.createCustomViewInternal(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:211) 
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.access$000(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:20) 
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:302) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3108) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3172) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1718) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3019) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:164) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:148) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.initTitle(ActionBarView.java:845) 
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.setDisplayOptions(ActionBarView.java:663) 
   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:227) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.createCustomViewInternal(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:211) 
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.access$000(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:20) 
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:302) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3108) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3172) 
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1718) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3019) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:327)
   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:695)
   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:637)
```

and also this one

```
Process: kamble.travelite.com, PID: 27350
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kamble.travelite.com/kamble.travelite.com.WebActivity2}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckBox
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckBox
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:164)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:148)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
   at kamble.travelite.com.WebActivity2.showDialog(WebActivity2.java:138)
   at kamble.travelite.com.WebActivity2.onCreate(WebActivity2.java:46)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:164) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:148) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
   at kamble.travelite.com.WebActivity2.showDialog(WebActivity2.java:138) 
   at kamble.travelite.com.WebActivity2.onCreate(WebActivity2.java:46) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:327)
   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:695)
   at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
   at android.widget.CompoundButton.<init>(CompoundButton.java:68)
   at android.widget.CheckBox.<init>(CheckBox.java:68)
   at android.widget.CheckBox.<init>(CheckBox.java:64)
```

successively.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dialog_close" />
```

This is the xml for the checkbox. The parent is a LinearLayout.

Comment: Need to see the XML files as well

Comment: im not even using any color but heres the whole layout:

Comment: Ok im new to stack overflow and when trying to post the xml file im getting an error that the body is too long.how do i do it

Comment: Im not even using a textview in that layout

Comment: Ive added my checkbox.Its parent is a linearlayout no textview

Comment: The issue was actually the theme my classes were extending.Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @Thekamble: care to explain this in an answer and accept it? This would be useful for others

Comment: @BenoitDuffez sorry I took long but I did just that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came about because I was using a theme that was not inheriting from `Theme.AppCompat`. That is why there was that error.For anyone getting a similar error.Check your theme first.Also you can consider using `Theme.AppCompat` for your apps.